# Assigning or modifying inherited attributes in rule and propagating results to parent rule

Tags: boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Say I have a Boost Spirit grammar like this, where a parent rule passes an inherited attribute to its children.

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct MyGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, vector<Foo>()>
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, vector<Foo>()> start;

    qi::rule<Iterator, vector<Foo>(Bar)> parent;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Foo(Bar)> child1;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Foo(Bar)> child2;

    MyGrammar() : MyGrammar::base_type(start)
    {
        start = parent( Bar(etc) ); // An "initial" value for the Bar passed
                                    // between the following rules.  More on
                                    // that later.

        parent = child1(_r1) >> child2(_r1);
        child1 = ...[do something with _r1];
        child2 = ...[do something with _r1];
    }
};
```

The *Foo* each the child rules return depends on the given *Bar* inherited attribute.  I might also have this for the parent rule:

```
parent = *child(_r1);
```

What I'm wondering is whether or not it is possible for a child rule to modify an inherited attribute, propagate the modification to its parent rule, and have the new value be passed to the next child rule.

In the example above, the *start* rule would be establishing an initial value for the *Bar* that gets used in *parent* and its child rules. The *Bar* gets modified every time it passes through a *child* rule. Is this even possible though, and what would such code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inherited attributes can be passed by reference:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, vector<Foo>(Bar)> parent;
qi::rule<Iterator, Foo(Bar&)> child1; 
qi::rule<Iterator, Foo(Bar&)> child2;
```

and:

```
parent = child1(phoenix::ref(_r1)) >> child2(phoenix::ref(_r1));
```

allowing to achieve exactly what you want.